# Is classical wordpress eidtor a good option for me to include a large table with a large number of images on my webpage?

Tags: plugins, images, editor, table

I am a beginner at using WordPress for my website. I generally design my website using the classical editor provided by WordPress and by installing very few plugins such as Beaver Builder and code syntax highlighter. I am not well aware of doing coding in PHP, CSS, etc.

Currently, **I need to include a large table of (thousands of) rows with at least 7 columns. Some of the columns include images and the others include strings are numbers.**

I can able to generate the table using python code, I just want to place the output into the web page.

The browser is getting slow when I try to copy thousands of lines using the WordPress classical editor. So I am getting the doubt whether the classical editor is a good option to do my task.

Is the classical editor of WordPress is a good option to work for in my task or do I need to work with any other plugin?

Comment: Please comment whether this is an on-topic question for this site. I am getting a sense of off-topic from [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). So, please guide me in this by commenting.

Comment: I'd suggest that any technology you use will have a problem displaying the huge tables you mention. Perhaps you should looks at an alternative, more efficient way of organizing your data?

Comment: @vancoder Actually, I am planning for a well-looking tutorial. So, I have no option other than to do this.